# Патовая ситуация на перекрестке

Tags: anylogic

Моделирую в AnyLogic перекресток.В начале функионирование нормальное, светофоры переключаются и в соотвествие с этим потоки движутся. Далее возникает затор (интенсивность потоков беру достаточно высокую от 3500 до 6000 авто в час в зависимости от направления) и потоки взаимоблокируются и не движутся вовсе, фазы светофора переключаются, но потоки стоят. В блоке Road Network Descriptor стоит флажок Авторазрешение заторов, однако машины не проезжают сквозь друг друга и затор не рассасывается вообще, т.к. автомобили не двигаются вовсе в течение оставшегося времени работы модели,и фазы работы светофора меняются "впустую".
При этом, если снизить интенсивность в 5 раз (до 800 авто в час в каждом направлении), то модель работает нормально, и по окончанию моделирования количество сгенерированных автомобилей в блоках carsourse равно примерно заданной интенсивности. При высокой же интенсивности кол-во сгенерированных в каждом блоке падает и составляет всего 200-300 авто в час в противовес 3500-6000 заданным).
Может кто-то подскажет, как исправить ситуацию, чтобы автомобили все-таки проезжали и заданная интенсивность была соблюдена при генерации автомобилей? Заранее спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы какое решение хотите получить: чтобы машины проезжали сквозь друг друга или как в реальной жизни?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы в модели автомобили не выезжали на перекресток под "занавес" так сказать. Ведь в реальной жизни все-таки на данном перекрестке машины не выезжают на сам перекресток (либо стараются встать на уровне разделительной линии) , видя ситуацию и зная, что они его не успеют пересечь. В модели же  часть машин очевидно. не успевая проехать перекресток, выезжают на него и остаются на нем, создавая помеху другому направлению.

Comment: Кроме того,  как я писала в вопросе, при интенсивности 800 авто в час, все 800 генерируются и пересекают перекресток. При повышении интенсивности, количество автомобилей , пересекших перекресток не достигает и 300.

Comment: И хотелось бы, чтобы если же все-таки авто выехали на сам перекресток, то водители поочередно пропускали друг друга. Вживую не стоит этот перекресток полчаса намертво. чтобы ни одна машина не проехала. Хоть и медленно, но поток движется.

Answer (score 1):

Решение здесь простое - не давать выезжать не перекрёсток, если он занят машинами с перпендикулярного направления. Если занятость перекрёстка получить нельзя, то просто при увеличении интенсивности движения нужно делать паузу между разрешающими сигналами (в обоих направлениях красный на въезд, а на продожение движения остаётся зелёный) чтобы машины могли покинуть перекрёсток, а новые заехать на него не могли.

Comment: Пауза есть - это желтый сигнал (для автомобилей он есть всегда). Отдельными авто , насколько я знаю, управлять, к сожалению, нельзя.

Comment: Лучше одновременно красный зажигать на первое направление, а на второе направление пусть остаётся зелёный там, где он был. И эту паузу нужно увеличивать при увеличении интенсивности движения.

Comment: Спасибо!Попробую